# Knockout where clause in foreach

Tags: knockout.js, foreach, where-clause

I would like to replicate this logic in knockout foreach.. any suggestions please? The current code is in razor and I am converting this to use knockoutJS

Where ItemStatus.Active is 0 in an enum in c# (backend)

```
    @foreach (var employee in Employees.Where(x => x.Status == ItemStatus.Active))
{   
      <div class="someclass”>
      <span class="label">Name:</span>
      <span class="value">@employee.Name</span> 
    </div>
    }
```

How do I replicate this logic in knockout foreach, ie I only want to show employees who are currently active or employed

thank you

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705453/knockout-foreach-with-a-where-clause?

Answer (score 1):

knockout's `computed` or `pureComputed` would do the trick.

Try with VM like this

```
function VM(data) {
    var self = this;
    //.............
    self.filter = ko.observable(null);
    self.data = ko.observableArray(data)

    self.filteredData = ko.pureComputed(function(){ 
        return self.data().filter(function(x){
            return !self.filter() || x.status == self.filter();
        })
    });
    self.setFilter = function(filter) {
        self.filter(filter || null);
    }
    //.........................
}
```

and markup like this

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:filteredData">
    <li data-bind="text:$data.value">
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-bind="click:setFilter(null)">all</a>
<a href="#" data-bind="click:setFilter('active')">active</a>
<a href="#" data-bind="click:setFilter('archived')">archived</a>
```

This little test application could be initialized like this

```
var someData = [
    {status:  'active', value:  'some active'},
    {status:  'active', value:  'another active'},
    {status:  'archived', value:  'some archived'},
    {status:  'archived', value:  'another archived'},
];
var vm = new VM(someData);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.setFilter(null);
```

Note that if your data array is static (no changes during the page lifecycle is expected) you may omit `self.data` observable array from the VM and just use `data` instead

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an array filter in my view model to solve that one, something along the lines of:

```
var self = this;

self.Employees = ko.observableArray();
ko.uitls.arrayfilter(self.Employees(), function(e) { return e.Status == 'Active' });
```

Make it really swish by working the array filter into a computed function and binding that to your div, there are plenty of documentation/tutorials on knockouts website to help you with this.

[Knockout Tutorial Website](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro)