# Knockout foreach with a where clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This sytax is in razor that I am converting to knockoutJS.. any help much appreciated..

```
Where ItemStatus.Active is 0 in an enum in c# ( backend )

@foreach (var employee in Employees.Where(x => x.Status == ItemStatus.Active))
{   
  <div class="someclass”>
  <span class="label">Name:</span>
  <span class="value">@employee.Name</span> 
  </div>
}
```

How do I replicate this logic in knockout foreach, ie I only want to show employees who are currently active or employed

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any JavaScript expression can be used in Knockout bindings.

So you could use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function (ES6):

```
<!-- ko foreach: Employees.filter(employee => employee.Status == 0) -->
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or any other method of filtering:

```
<!-- ko foreach: ko.utils.arrayFilter(Employees.filter, function(employee) { return employee.Status == 0; }) -->
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Sorry I get filter is not a function as Employees is an observable array coming from a VM..

Comment: option 1 worked, I had to do some changes like Employees was an observablearray and Status was observable too. Hence my final code look s like 


<div data-bind="foreach:Employees().filter(item=>item.Status() == 0)"> 
....
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Razor runs server-side. So, you can't use `Employees` with knockout bindings which are apllied client-side. You need to hand over this `Employees` data to a javascript variable, and then bind that using knockout which will run client-side, after the page loads.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script>
    // cretes a js array of active employees
    var activeEmployees = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Employees.Where(x => x.Status == ItemStatus.Active)));

    var viewModel = {
      Employees: ko.observableArray(activeEmployees)
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Use the [`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding in your HTML like this (Here `Employees` refers to the property of your knockout `viewModel`, not MVC)

```
<!-- ko foreach: Employees -->
<div class="someclass">
  <span class="label">Name:</span>
  <span class="value" data-bind="text:Name"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

You also need to add `@using Newtonsoft.Json` to the top your `cshtml` file for `JsonConvert`

Comment: Hi Adiga, that is all done and I am using to bind all vm arrays and variables to bind as observables like below..
     MyVm = function (data) {
            var self = this;
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);}

Comment: @Pravi It's not clear what `data` is here. Please update the question with all the relevant code.